# why there is showing "php executable is not set" in vs code?

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, visual-studio-code

VS code notification error:

[image]

I want to use php latest version 7. I installed xamp latest version. Now in vs code it is showing php executable is not set. How can i fix it?

Comment: It tells you in the next sentence of the error message!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
File -> Presences -> User Settings
```

Now you can see 2 windows. In the right window add below codes:

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "path",
    "php.executablePath": "path"
}
```

Here `Path`is the location of `php.exe`. Example: `C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.0.4\\php.exe`

Comment: how can i find the path? on my windows 10. i installed xamp in C drive.